# die Rechtstruktur in den/dem Katalog einbauen?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

I know that I should say:

> Ich wohne in **der** Stadt.

and

> Ich fahre in **die** Stadt.

Because *direction* is involved in the second verb.

However, should I say:

> Muss die Rechtstruktur **im** Katalog eingebaut werden?

or

> Muss die Rechtstruktur in **den** Katalog eingebaut werden?

Since it is not clear to me whether direction is involved in building a set of rights permissions into a catalog or not.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could change the tile to its English equivalent, I fear if it loses some points you'd like to include if I do it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand. Do you mean change the title to something like "Should I use 'im' or 'den' in this sentence?"

Comment: Yes exactly, an English title is preferable for the English body.

Comment: Now that they've corrected the errors in the title, better not to edit it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... building a set of rights permissions **into** a catalog ...

"into" is your clue; it indicates direction.

Compare:

"Ich wohne **in der** Stadt." -- "I live **in** the city."

"Ich fahre **in die** Stadt." -- "I drive **into** the city."

Thus, "Muss die Rechtstruktur in **den** Katalog eingebaut werden?" is correct.

Note also you're missing a "Fugenelement" in "Rechtstruktur". It should be either "Rechtestruktur" (I'd use that with, say, access rights on a computer) or "Rechtsstruktur" (when it's about the law).

---

To confuse you entirely:  "... die Rechtestruktur im Katalog einbauen..." works, too. I suppose I'd go with the accusative, though.

Comment: "im Katalog einbauen" can has a different meaning then "in den Katalog", depending on the context; so better to use the more clear "in den"…

Comment: thanks for the "into" tip, that seems to be pretty much 1-to-1 with English, nice

Answer (score 1):

Besser

> ... in **den** Katalog ...

Dagegen würde ich „**im** Katalog“ nur dann nutzen, wenn der Katalog bereits einen bestimmten Textabschnitt enthält und nur noch geklärt werden muss, **wo** im Katalog er endgültig untergebracht werden soll.

Zur Terminologie: Das Verb „einbauen“ ist in dem Kontext vielleicht etwas zu technisch - man baut ein Bauteil oder eine Komponente ein. Für Text würde ich eher „einfügen“ oder „in den Katalog **aufnehmen**“ nutzen. „Rechtstruktur“ ist m.E. ungebräuchlich, ich bin dem Begriff noch nie begegnet. Je nachdem, worum es im Detail geht, wäre vielleicht „Lizenztext“, „Lizenzhinweis“ oder „rechtlicher Hinweis“ besser.

Comment: Bei "Rechtstruktur in den Katalog einbauen" habe ich zuerst an eine Rechteverwaltung in einer Software gedacht – insofern kann auch ein technisches Wort passend sein, aber wie du sagtest, kommt das auf Kontext an.

Answer (score 1):

> Muss die Rechtstruktur im Katalog eingebaut werden?

This is equivalent to "Ich wohne in der Stadt", there is no direction involved, the "Rechtstruktur " is already in the catalog in this case and you ask whether to do something with it.

> Muss die Rechtstruktur in den Katalog eingebaut werden?

With the Akkusativ, a direction is implied - the "Rechtstruktur" is not yet in the catalog and now you ask whether or not to put it there.